# Recursive Copy Package Files With Gulp in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, npm, asp.net-core

Within Visual Studio 2015 for .NET Core Web Application-

With Gulp I’m trying to Move specific packages that were created with the NPM Package Manager.

I installed jQuery 1.11.3 with NPM:  `npm install jquery@1.11.3 –S`

It was added to to `node_modules` directory and `package.json`

I need to move those packages to `wwwroot/lib`

[image]

I'm using Gulp and I came up with a Script within gulpfile.js  to move:
`/jquery/dist Directory` with all of its files
from `node_modules` 
to `wwwroot/lib Directory`

```
gulp.task('copyjquery', function () {
  gulp.src('./node_modules/jquery/**/*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib'));
});
```

However this script does not move the actual Folder *jquery*, it only moves the Folder *dist* with contents.  I need the jquery Folder moved as well.

Can anyone see the issue with my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used npm to install jQuery, it should've created a folder called node_modules (possibly hidden in Solution Explorer).  You have to write some script (gulp, grunt, etc) to move the files you need out of that node_modules directory, and into your wwwroot/lib.

Answer (score 1):

```
gulp.task('copy', ['clean'], function () {
   return gulp.src(['./node_modules/jquery/**/*'], {
       base: 'node_modules'
   }).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib'));
});
```